# Running two SQL queries in VBA MS Access. The second recordset depends on the first recordset

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset

I am currently using VBA access and I want the information from strSQL to come from strSQL0. Please help me correct my select statement for strSQL.

The logic for strSQL is I want to select the minimum iD in from the recordist produced by strSQL0

```
strSQL0 = "SELECT Promis_lt_generating_numbers_SubjectID_step2.* " _
            & "FROM Promis_lt_generating_numbers_SubjectID_step2 LEFT JOIN PROMIS_LT ON Promis_lt_generating_numbers_SubjectID_step2.[Id] = PROMIS_LT.[DadosID]" _
            & "WHERE (((PROMIS_LT.DadosID) Is Null));"

    Set rs0 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL0)
    

    strSQL = "SELECT MIN(rs![Id]) AS New_SubjectID" _
            & "FROM rs0![*];"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trim the first SQL to deliver the value without a second SQL:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 Id " & _
    "FROM Promis_lt_generating_numbers_SubjectID_step2 " & _
    "LEFT JOIN PROMIS_LT ON Promis_lt_generating_numbers_SubjectID_step2.[Id] = PROMIS_LT.[DadosID] " & _
    "WHERE PROMIS_LT.DadosID Is Null " & _
    "ORDER BY Id ASC;"

    Set rs0 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    SubjectID = rs0(0).Value
    rs0.Close
```